# Aws Elastic Load Balancing security group not allowing inbound calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, varnish, amazon-elb

I have the following structure running on AWS:

Cloudfront -> Varnish -> Nginx -> Elb -> Ec2 instances.

Varnish and Nginx are running on same ec2 instance. The problem is that nginx can only make a requisition to my Elb if I let the inbound traffic opened to anywhere in the security group. I don't want to let my Elb opened to anywhere, I just want to my Nginx to make reqs to Elb. If I try to change the security group of my Elb to only allow calls of nginx, it does not work. Does anybody know what this could be?

Comment: what is CIDR in both Nginx and ELB ?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get the question. I put the security group of Nginx instance on the inbound calls of my Elb security group. It does not work. If I let open to anywhere, it works. They are all on the defaul vpc.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the security group configuration for the ELB. Also, how is Nginx referring to the ELB -- is it using a DNS name or an IP address? It sounds like it might be attempting to contact the ELB via a Public IP address rather than having the DNS name resolve to a Private IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are using an Internet facing ELB. This case the ELB DNS will resolve to public IPs regardless of whether you are resolving it from within the same VPC or outside the VPC. Security group rules referring other security groups are not applicable in this case.

This is unlike EC2 instances whose DNS will resolve to private IPs within the VPC and public IPs outside the VPC.

Two possible solutions:
1. Assign an Elastic IP to the Varnish/Nginx instance and allow that IP in the ELB security group.
2. Use an internal ELB which resolves to private IPs if it suits your use-case.